# jQuery alert when form select input is not selected

Tags: jquery

I want to display an alert when a drop down menu's selected value is equal to 'not supplied', here is my js:

```
function ValForm() {
if($('#location option:selected').val('not supplied')) {
    alert("Please select a location.");
    $('#location').focus();
    return false;
}
return true;
}
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<form name="contact" method="post" onsubmit="return ValForm();">
    <div class="control-group">
        <div class="controls">
            <select name="location" id="location" class="span12">
                <option value="not supplied">Location</option>
                <option value="option1">Option 1</option>
                <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
                <option value="option3">Option 3</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Obviously I have a submit button but I've just not included it, I have 4 other form fields that are text, the JS for them is all working fine, it's just the select button, thinking I might have the syntax or something wrong.

I can't seem to work out why it's literally not doing anything, any help is appreciated.

Comment: You are setting value here: `$('#location option:selected').val('not supplied')`

Comment: I don't think this question should be downvoted....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check it like this -

```
if($('#location').val() == 'not supplied'){
  //alert
}
```

`----->` http://api.jquery.com/val/

Answer (score 1):

You should try

```
if($('#location').val() == 'not supplied') { .. }
```

Comment: try dumping the content of $('#location').val()

Answer (score 1):

for comparing you will have to write like below coz in ur case you are setting value instead of getting

```
if($('#location').val() == 'not supplied'){
  alert("Please select a location.");
  $('#location').focus();
  return false;
}
```

please go through the fiddle I have made some changes including in html also.

http://jsfiddle.net/avmCX/20/

Answer (score 0):

Do following=>

```
if($('#location').val() === 'not supplied')
{
 alert("Please select a location.");
    $('#location').focus();
    return false;
}
```

You were setting value using val("something") .Here i get value and then compare against other value.